# Mac Networking Troubles

Tags: mac, networking, macbook

My network consists of an old Powerbook G4 Titanium running Mac OS X 10.4.6 and a recent iMac running Mac OS X 10.6.1 . The network is run through Ethernet, not wireless.

I have issues accessing the iMac from the Powerbook. It appeared once via Finder>Network then disappeared and then reappears occasionnally, but nothing reliable enough for even a large file transfer.

Any idea what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you ping the other systems?  (eg Macbook ping the imac, imac ping the macbook).

Don't forget to use IPs, not the hostnames...

It could be that your router or switch is not allowing the machines to be visible to each other, or you have the firewall enabled.. (I think 10.6 has that on by default?)...

Try networking to the other computer directly, bypassing the network browser...

Try Finder --> Connect to Server --> afp://<.ip address.> --> Connect

Answer (score 0):

Under system preferences » sharing, check that file sharing is enabled for AFP.  Simply having the box checked might not do the trick as there are three different services.

Click the options box and see if your services are turned on.

Keep in mind, Snow Leopard doesn't have AppleTalk, but instead uses TCP/IP for the networking.

Comment: It is enabled for AFP.